# Summing binary numbers representing fractions in Sagemath

Tags: binary, addition, sage, fractions

I'm just starting to learn how to code in Sagemath, I know it's similar to python but I don't have much experience with that either.
I'm trying to add two binary numbers representing fractions. That is, something like

```
a = '110'  
b = '011'  
bin(int(a,2) + int(b,2))
```

But using values representing fractions, such as '1.1'.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in vanilla Python, parsing the binary fractions by hand isn't too bad (the first part being from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662933/how-to-convert-a-string-representing-a-binary-fraction-to-a-number-in-python/13662978#13662978));

```
def binstr_to_float(s):
    t = s.split('.')
    return int(t[0], 2) + int(t[1], 2) / 2.**len(t[1])

def float_to_binstr(f):
    i = 0
    while int(f) != f:
        f *= 2
        i += 1
    as_str = str(bin(int(f)))
    if i == 0:
        return as_str[2:]
    return as_str[2:-i] + '.' + as_str[-i:]

float_to_binstr(parse_bin('11.1') + parse_bin('0.111'))  # is '100.011'
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you can use the [Binary fractions](https://pypi.org/project/binary-fractions/) package. With this package you can convert binary-fraction strings into floats and vice-versa. Then, you can perform operations on them.

Example:

```
>>> from binary_fractions import Binary
>>> sum = Binary("1.1") + Binary("10.01")
>>> str(sum)
'0b11.11'
>>> float(sum)
3.75
>>>
```

It has many more helper functions to manipulate binary strings such as: shift, add, fill, to_exponential, invert...

PS: Shameless plug, I'm the author of this package.